# Delete Azure Container App Environment using Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-container-apps

I am using below Azure Powershell command to remove an ACA Environment, but it is not working:

`Remove-AzAppServiceEnvironment -Name fer-bpbu-d-cae-euwe-dev  -ResourceGroupName "fer-bpbu-d-rsg-conapp"`

[image]

Unable to find appropriate command to remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **delete** Azure Container App Environment using Azure PowerShell, you can run below command:

```
Remove-AzContainerAppManagedEnv -EnvName <env_name> -ResourceGroupName <rg_name>
```

I have one Azure Container App Environment named **`srienv`** with 0 container apps like below:

[image]

To get the above **environment details** from Azure PowerShell, you can run below command:

```
Get-AzContainerAppManagedEnv -EnvName  srienv -ResourceGroupName Sri
```

**Response:**

[image]

To delete the above Container App Environment, I ran below command:

```
Get-AzContainerAppManagedEnv -EnvName  srienv -ResourceGroupName Sri | Remove-AzContainerAppManagedEnv
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, Container App Environment named `srienv` **deleted** successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Remove-AzContainerAppManagedEnv (Az.App) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.app/remove-azcontainerappmanagedenv?view=azps-10.0.0)

Comment: Thanks ! @Sridevi : Can you answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667392/enable-internal-load-balancing-mode-for-container-app-environment-using-azure-te)?