# Enable Internal Load Balancing Mode for Container App Environment using Azure Terraform AzApi Provider

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-apps

For an ACA Environment, How do I enable Internal balancer mode using `AzApi` Terraform provider. Here is current configuration:

```
resource "azapi_resource" "aca_env" {
  for_each = { for aca_env in var.aca_envs : aca_env.name => aca_env} 
  type      = "Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-11-01-preview"
  name      = each.value.name
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  location  = each.value.location
  
  body   = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      appLogsConfiguration = {
        destination               = "log-analytics"
        logAnalyticsConfiguration = {
          customerId = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law["${each.value.name}-law"].workspace_id
          sharedKey  = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.law["${each.value.name}-law"].primary_shared_key
        }
      }
      vnetConfiguration = {
        "internal" = true
        "infrastructureSubnetId" = data.azurerm_subnet.subnets[each.value.subnet_id].id
      }
      workloadProfiles = [
        {
          name = "Consumption"
          workloadProfileType = "Consumption"
        }
      ]
    }
 })
}
```

I am aware of `azurerm`'s  `azurerm_container_app_environment` exposes attribute `internal_load_balancer_enabled` for this. But how to do this with `AzAPI` provider?

Comment: If you set **[internal = true](https://i.imgur.com/eJKfOIj.png)** in Vnet configuration section in your terraform code, The Internal environment are deployed with Virtual IP, The internal endpoint is an [Azure internal load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking#accessibility-levels)  and IP addresses are issued from the custom VNet's list of private IP addresses.
[ACE creation from portal](https://i.imgur.com/iJakPSy.png%29) after select the [Load Balancer option](https://i.imgur.com/h5PjpHB.png)

Comment: Could you please convert this to Answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create container app environment with `internalLoadBalancer` you can use `"internal = true"` if you are using **Azure Terraform AzApi Provider**.

I have created `container app environment` with **internalLoadBalancer** using **Azure Terraform AzApi Provider**.

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source = "azure/azapi"
      }
    } 
    }
        provider "azapi" {}
        provider "azurerm" {
        features {}
    }

    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "venkatnetwork" {
      name = "acceptanceTestVirtualNetwork1test"
      address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location = "eastus"
      resource_group_name = "venkattests-resources"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "venkatsub" {
      name = "testsubnet1"
      resource_group_name = "venkattests-resources"
      virtual_network_name =azurerm_virtual_network.venkatnetwork.name
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
      delegation {
        name = "acctestdelegation"
        service_delegation {
          name = "Microsoft.App/environments"
          actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
        }
      }
    }
    
    resource "azapi_resource" "aca_env" {
      type = "Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-11-01-preview"
      name = "my-aca-env-name"
      parent_id = "/subscriptions/xxxxxx-7f0905ec6833/resourceGroups/venkattests-resources"
      location = "eastus"
      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
        vnetConfiguration = {
          "internal" = true
          "infrastructureSubnetId" = azurerm_subnet.venkatsub.id
        }
         workloadProfiles = [
        {
        name = "Consumption"
        workloadProfileType = "Consumption"
        }
      ]
    }
    })
    }
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

If you set **internal = true** in Vnet configuration section in your terraform code, The Internal environment are deployed with **Virtual IP**, The internal endpoint is an [Azure internal load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking#accessibility-levels)  and IP addresses are issued from the custom VNet's list of private IP addresses.

[image]

If I try to create a `container app environment` with a load balancer from the portal for testing, will the output be the same as a `Terraform` deployment.

I have selected **Internal** under `virtual IP` section.

[image]

Container app with **Load Balancer(Virtual IP)**.

[image]